# Python: Best method to reload class in XMLRPC Server

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I have a multit-threaded xmlrpc service running which stores a huge amount of data ~2G in memory.  Currently, if I want to update a method the server exposes I have to restart the service.  The problem here is that if I restart the service it needs to load all of the data it had in memory back into memory by using a database or using shelved data.

I am using methods like this:

```
xmlrpc_getUser(self, uid):
    return self.users[uid]
```

What I was hoping I could do is just use these methods as a proxy to another module, so my methods would look more like this

```
xmlrpc_getUser(self, uid):
    return self.proxy.getUser(uid)
```

This way I could update code on the development server then simply copy my update proxy module to the production server without the need for a restart.

I tried adding 
import service_proxy
to the constructor of my xmlrpc service controller, but I think the module is cached and won't reload.

Is there a good way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) method. You would need to write some code to check the last modified time of the modules file.

Comment: Note that the [`reload` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) has moved in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

If reload doesn't work, you could try `twisted.python.rebuild`; your application need not be written in Twisted to use this twisted.python utility.

I also recently saw this [livecoding](http://code.google.com/p/livecoding/) thing ("a code reloading library for Python"), but it talks about a custom module system and I don't know what's going on there.